# Entering date in a mysql database with classic asp

Tags: mysql, sql, asp-classic

First message here, I dont know why I waited for so long.
So I am currently fixing a website built with classic asp using mysql database.

In the database, there is a date field with datetime type.
So the person who programmed it before wanted to enter the date in the database with NOW().
NOW() is not working and I would assume it to work only on Sql Server.
What function can I replace NOW() with to have the date entered in the 2013-02-13 22:36:10 format?

Thanks

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS (REFERERID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, DATEJOINED) 
       VALUES ('"& Session("MEMBERID") &"', '"& FIRSTNAME &"', '"& LASTNAME &"', 
       '"& NOW() &"')"
Set objAddCus = objConn.execute(SQL)
```

Comment: `NOW()` is MySQL specific. But if you wanted to try an alternative  use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Really? But I checked the database just now, its not entering the date with NOW(). Database columns all filled with 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: `NOW()` is not a valid function in MS SQL server, it is used in [asp vbscript](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_now.asp), Try to use `NOW` without `()`

Comment: Read. Learn. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Actually I am pretty sure that NOW() works with Sql Server. I just need to learn the equivalent of it for Mysql. As for the sql injection, not relevant with my question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ;)

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS (REFERERID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, DATEJOINED) 
   VALUES ('"& Session("MEMBERID") &"', '"& FIRSTNAME &"', '"& LASTNAME &"', NOW() )"
Set objAddCus = objConn.execute(SQL)
```

Mysql can handle now() in that way, like a part of the query, not like an asp function ;)

Saludos,